# HTML Form will not submit in IE9

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple HTML form that will not submit in IE9. It works in Chrome, FF, and IE10.

I have tried to submit in IE9 on Windows 7 and IE10 on Windows 8.

IE10 works unless I change the browser mode to IE9; then it won't submit.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/582/).  If you click "Save" on any working browser, it'll take you to the fake demo_form.asp.

Here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Title</title> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <div class="error-messsage">
                    <p/>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <form action="demo_form.asp" data-ajax="false" method="get">
                        <input type="hidden" name="scoreType" id="_scoreType" value="T"/>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                                <div class="ui-block-a">Minutes:</div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">Seconds:</div>
                                <div class="ui-block-a">
                                    <input type="number" name="score_minutes" value="1" id="_scoreMinutes" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" data-inline="true"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-block-b">
                                    <input type="number" name="score_seconds" value="2" id="_scoreSeconds" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" data-inline="true"/>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" name="score" id="_score" value="62"/>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="_note">Note:</label>
                            <textarea name="note" cols="40" rows="10" id="_note" autocomplete="off"/>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="_classAttended" class="select">Class Time:</label>
                            <select name="class_attended" id="_classAttended" data-native-menu="false">
                                <option value="-1"/>
                                <option value="6">06:00 am</option>>
</select>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="_memberRating" class="select">Member Rating:</label>
                            <select name="member_rating" id="_memberRating" data-native-menu="false">
                                <option value="-1"/>
                                <option value="5">5 </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="_rx">RX</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="rx" value="1" id="_rx" data-mini="true"/>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <a href="http://mysite.com/index.php/welcome/index/TRUE" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Cancel</a>
                            <button name="" type="Submit" id="_submit" class="ui-btn-hidden" value="Save" aria-disabled="false" data-inline="true" data-theme="b"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the "compatibility mode" settings?

Comment: What happens if you replace `<button` by `<input`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `<div>` that's trying to be inside a `<form>` that's inside a `<p>`. But `<div>`s can't be inside a `<p>`, so the HTML parser closes the `<p>` element, and in doing so also closes the `<form>`. So the save button is not inside the form, and in consequence IE9 doesn't know what to submit when you click the button. Remove the `<p>` tags that surround the `<form>`.

The HTML5 parser as used in FF, Chrome and IE10 has some nifty tricks to cope with your invalid markup, but the older IE9 parser cannot cope.

Also, you have `<p/>` and `<textarea/>`. Don't do that. Self closing syntax is not supported for either element.

Comment: It didn't check the validity of his HTML, but imho people should always make sure that their code validates before they ask questions about it. If it doesn't validate, they should get this fixed first...